# Ubuntu - Internet isnt working nor popping up

Tags: networking, internet

I am COMPLETELY new to Ubuntu, like literally, I only know a few commands and stuff for terminal.. I recently installed it into my laptop to learn it more but for some odd reason my wifi wont pick up, nor will it accept wired connections.. Im currently running version 12.04 and I'm in dire need of assistance. I wish I could give you guys more to work with but im stoked, i have no idea how to fix this. I tried changing my interface settings(gksu gedit /etc/network/interfaces) to

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

with was a method i found on google but no luck.. Can anyone help me out please????

-EDIT-

when I type `dmesg | grep -i eth` i get this

```
[    0.094674] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[    0.104787] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0._OSC] (Node f5029dc8), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20120320/psparse-536)
[    0.109074] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0._OSC] (Node f5029dc8), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20120320/psparse-536)
[    0.109130] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0._OSC] (Node f5029dc8), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20120320/psparse-536)
[    1.794527] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[   16.730616] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
```

and when I type `dmesg | grep -i net` i get this.

```
[    0.000000]   Transmeta GenuineTMx86
[    0.084004] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.114632] NetLabel: Initializing
[    0.114633] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[    0.114635] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
[    0.114648] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[    0.163609] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.163898] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.163898] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    0.783442] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    0.783652] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[   16.013583] kernel BUG at include/net/cfg80211.h:2351!
[   16.419997] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   16.730616] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   17.261656] type=1400 audit(1371348543.594:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=669 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   20.441385] type=1400 audit(1371348546.774:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=843 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Comment: What is the manufacturer and model number of the device that you are using to connect to the internet with a wired connection? Is this device a modem or is it a router?

Comment: Modem, Im using ethernet

Comment: Sorry guys if this is incorrect but this is Siren, I had to login through Facebook but im using a Inspriron 1501. It works fine on my vista but not my laptop

Comment: And no I didnt Wouter

Comment: What is the output of `lspci -nn | egrep '0280|0200'` and `sudo lshw -c network`?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to include info about your laptop.

Using a 12.04 live disc for testing might be your option.

The live session should automatically find any active eth0 and connect to it.

If there is a wireless signal nearby it will also advise that a connection is available.

This you should be able to connect to with your access password for the wlan0.

If neither is occurring then you must have an issue with on board LAN & / or on board wireless device/s.

Good luck

Look up this Old "Ubuntu help" for the Dell Driver on your Vista machine.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper#Configuration

And this for the ethernet connection.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsWiredNetworkCards

Answer (score 0):

If your wireless device is not supported in linux, you could try Ndiswrapper there is a gui in the software center: ndisgtk. I have never needed it, but you could give it a try.

Comment: can i install it offline?? and how do i do so? whats the command?

Comment: @Siren I guess you could download the packages [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ndisgtk), also make sure to download all the dependencies. But it works more easy if you could find an Ethernet cable to plug in...

Comment: I have one, but it wont pick up, and i notced in ym network settings the wired was set too off. i set it to on, left,then went back to it it was off again

Comment: oh sorry I misread, did the wired connection also not working before you made the changes in /etc/network/interfaces?